# Corda: Questions about token SDK

Tags: corda

I have been playing around with Token SDK. Here I have a question.

I made a new token class that extends the FungibleToken class so that I can add some information (e.g. an account ID) into the Token. I also made schema and PersistentState for the new token so that I can query the token by account ID.

My problem is, in order to use the new schema, I think I need to override the generateMappedObject() and supportedSchemas() functions. However, since supportedSchemas() in the FungibleToken returns a List of FungibleTokenSchemaV1, I cannot override the supportedSchemas() function.

Can someone give me some advice about how to extend the FungibleToken (and also the NonFungibleToken)?

Question from Corda-Ledger Slack: http://slack.corda.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you want but i wouldn't advise it.

You should use the accounts library if you want to use accounts with your cordapp: github.com/corda/accounts

You only need to sub-class fungible token if you are adding new functionality to the contract
otherwise you just create your own token types by implementing `TokenType`
it’s open because we (the maintainers) might want to add, say, `WhitelistedFungibleToken` or something like that

Token type is the information about the token itself. You can add information about account by creating new token type, **BUT** it is probably not a good idea.

You should use the accounts library instead, it manages accounts for you… you don't need to put account ids in your states. The public keys in the states are used to link the states to a particular account

Here is the link about the accounts feature: https://github.com/corda/accounts

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the Corda token SDK.

1. git clone the repository
2. load the repository in IDE and modify the file `token-sdk/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/states/FungibleToken.kt`, line 66, with

   ```
   override fun supportedSchemas() : List<MappedSchema> = 
   listOf(FungibleTokenSchemaV1)
   ```
3. Don't forget to sign your cordapp:
   copy (or create) your P12 certificate in `token-sdk/cert/` modify `build.gradle` (in contracts and workflows directory) files with signing options

   ```
   signing {
       enabled true
       options {
           keystore "${rootProject.projectDir}/cert/deepKeystore.jks"
           alias "cordapp-signer"
           storepass "password"
           keypass "password"
           storetype "PKCS12"
       }
   }
   ```
4. modify "tokens_release_version" field in build.gradle file with tokens_release_version = "1.2.3-XXXX"
5. build JARS with `./gradlew jar`
6. verify jars are signed `jarsigner -verify tokens-contracts-1.2.3-XXXX.jar`

   Now you can override the `supportedSchemas` function. You will use tokens-contracts-1.2.3-XXXX.jar and tokens-workflows-1.2.3-XXXX.jar in your cordapp (instead of the official tokens-contracts-1.2.3.jar version).
7. In your cordapp, don't forget to  modify the `build.gradle` file to specify the path of your tokens-contracts-1.2.3-XXXX.jar.
   Personnaly, I just copied the 2 Jars in a "libs" folder at the root of my cordapp and modified the build.gradle file in `repositories` section:

   ```
   flatDir {
       dirs "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs"
   }
   ```