# Error when extending FungibleToken: supportedSchemas() in QueryableState clashes with supportedSchemas() in FungibleState

Tags: corda

I'm using the **Java** template (`token-template` branch), tokens SDK version is `1.1-SNAPSHOT`.

I'm extending `FungibleToken` class to add one extra attribute (`PublicKey owningAccount`) and I'm getting this error inside Intellij (as red underlines):

```
supportedSchemas() in QueryableState clashes with supportedSchemas() in FungibleState, attempting to use incompatible type
```

When I add the below function; the compile error is gone (Intellij no longer shows red underlines), but I get a different error on `./gradlew deployNodes`:

```
@NotNull
@Override
public List<FungibleTokenSchemaV1> supportedSchemas() {
    return super.supportedSchemas();
}
```

Build error:

```
> Task :contracts:compileJava FAILED
MyToken.java:33: error: supportedSchemas() in MyToken cannot implement supportedSchemas() in QueryableState
    public List<FungibleTokenSchemaV1> supportedSchemas() {
                                       ^
  return type List<FungibleTokenSchemaV1> is not compatible with Iterable<MappedSchema>
1 error
```

Even though `List` is `Iterable` and `FungibleTokenSchemaV1` is `MappedSchmea`.

Full code of class:

```java
public class MyToken extends FungibleToken {

    private final PublicKey owningAccount;

    public Shoken(Amount<IssuedTokenType> amount,
                  AbstractParty holder,
                  SecureHash tokenTypeJarHash,
                  PublicKey owningAccount) {
        super(amount, holder, tokenTypeJarHash);
        this.owningAccount = owningAccount;
    }

    public PublicKey getOwningAccount() {
        return owningAccount;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<FungibleTokenSchemaV1> supportedSchemas() {
        return super.supportedSchemas();
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, Roger Willis explained that there's no need to add `owningAccount` since `Holder` can be used to hold the owning account, but regardless; if it is required to extend `FungibleToken` currently there's no possibility to do so.

Comment: I think you can fork the Corda Token SDK ... see post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756951/corda-questions-about-token-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `evolvableTokentype` to issue tokens with evolvable attributes. The `FungibleToken` and `NonFungibleToken` objects are only the instruments that carries the issuance of the tokens. The underlying template of the token is what stores the information.

Feel free to look at our TokenSDK workshop at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAViczRAEyU.